# Use a custom function to apply on a df column if a condition is satisfied

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like

```
A   B
1   2
2   -
5   -
4   5
```

I want to apply a function `func()` on column B (but the function gives an error if `-` is passed). I cannot modify the `func()` function. I need something like:

`df['B']=df['B'].apply(func)` only if value not equal to `-`

Answer (score 2):

**Use a custom function to apply on a df column if a condition is satisfied:**

```
def func(a): 
    return a + 10  
#new pandas dataframe with four rows and 2 columns.  3rd row having a nan 
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, pd.np.nan], [7, 8]], columns=["A", "B"]) 
print(df) 
#coerce column named B to numeric
s = pd.to_numeric(df['B'], errors='coerce') 
#a mask has true for numeric rows, false for non numeric rows 
mask = s.notna() 
#mask 
print(mask) 
#run function named func across the B column 
df.loc[mask, 'B'] = s[mask].apply(func) 
print(df)
```

**Which prints:**

```
   A    B
0  1  2.0
1  3  4.0
2  5  NaN
3  7  8.0

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True

   A     B
0  1  12.0
1  3  14.0
2  5   NaN
3  7  18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['B'] = df[df['B']!='-']['B'].apply(func)
```

Or when the `-` is actaully `nan` you can use:

```
df['B'] = df[pd.notnull(df['B'])]['B'].apply(func)
```

Comment: got this error
"cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"